# Query Expansion in Perl

Tags: perl, text

Is there any existing implementation for query expansion in Perl?
By query expansion I mean, when the user enter a query in our database
it will expand the search based on related terms.

In principle we have a XML file (e.g. [MESH](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/)) with which 
we want to refer to for query expansion.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: For example when user enter query "heart attack" it will also perform search based on a term “myocardial infarction”. Such mapping uses relationship in the XML file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bio::DB::MeSH - Term retrieval from a Web MeSH database

```
my $mesh = Bio::DB::MeSH->new();
my $term = $mesh->get_exact_term('Butter');
print $term->description;
```

Answer (score 3):

You got a serviceable answer already but there is a far deeper and more robust alternative for more serious usage: [UMLS::Similarity](https://metacpan.org/module/UMLS%3a%3aSimilarity) and [UMLS::Interface](https://metacpan.org/module/UMLS%3a%3aInterface). The problem being these are a little bit of a bear to install, require MySQL, take up quite a bit of disk space, and require you to have the MeSH stuff locally and make sure your usage is in compliance with a couple dozen related licenses for the dictionaries/sources.

I do not mean to disparage [Bio::DB::MeSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Bio%3a%3aDB%3a%3aMeSH), it's useful and part of a bigger picture ([BioPerl](https://metacpan.org/release/BioPerl)), but it has fragile heuristics and is at the mercy of availability and trivial HTML changes in the target/source site (it was broken the last time I used it for example though it was easy to patch locally).